# How to restrict the access to DB resources in WebAPI

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I am making a WebAPI service. I just used the ASP.NET WebAPI template with authentication. I was wondering how can we restrict DB entity access for those users who are already logged in. With [Authorize] we can restrict unauthorized users, which I have done. After login, they can access anything right now. Eg: I have a table Bill. With BillId, users who are authorized can access any entry in Bill table. How to restrict this? Currently Bill table has no relation with UserIdentity tables!!.

Comment: Well, it seems like you already know what to do. You need to create a mechanism for "permissions" or "roles" if you mean. Each authenticated user should have a role and every time a user wants to access something, you should confront to its permissions.

Comment: As @jpgrassi says, you probably want role based access. Once users are in roles you can extend the authorize attribute like `[Authorize(Roles="whatever")]`

Comment: If there are 2 users with same role, both can access data belong to the other user because they are of the same role. How can we restrict this?

Comment: The question then really is how you do authorization on access to "Bills" right now. If there is no relationship between a principal / user and an entity, then access can't be configured. You have to find out what that relationship is before worrying about how to restrict access to the entity.

Comment: The entity relationship goes like this. Bill table is related to MedicalRecord table, MedicalRecord is related to Member table and Member table is associated with UserIdentity table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about the scenario, I have a solution [Not sure the best]. In all my controllers I can get the Userid [Authenticated user's id]. When a user adds data to any entity, I will add userid as a column to that entity and store userid. When any user looks for a resource, he will get only those resources which are of his Userid. I am not giving any relation to any user table but just adding the userid to all entities as a new column.